# Cannot find symbol al hacer Do While comparando un Caracter

Tags: java

> Error (error: cannot find symbol)

Al hacer `do-while` comparando un " < " con `equals()`:
El objetivo es localizar palabras que comiencen con el carácter "<".

```
String texto = "Erase una vez el <lobo> y <caperucita>.";
    Scanner linea = new Scanner(texto);
    do{
        String palabra = linea.next();
        char caract = palabra.charAt(0);
    }while(caract.equals("<"));
```

El programa debe buscar las palabras lobo y caperucita.

Comment: Para que usas `palabra`?

Comment: corregido. Para buscar su primer caracter.

Comment: El error ocurre porque declaras `caract` dentro del bloque `do {  ... }` por lo que el objeto es visible únicamente dentro de ese bloque. No puedes usarlo aquí para saber su valor `while(caract.equals("<")` porque no es su ámbito. Debes declararlo fuera del bloque o hacer otro tipo de evaluación que asignas a una variable booleana. Otra cosa, para comparar `char` tienes que usar `==` y poner el valor entre comillas simples, en vez de esto: `caract.equals("<")` la comparaicón sería así: `caract=='<'` Una cosa que no entiendo es por qué usas un scanner cuando tienes un texto predefinido ¿?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar `char`, es un tipo primitivo de dato<sup>1</sup>, por lo mismo este tipo de dato no contiene ningún método, pero puedes comparar con `==`,por eso no es posible utilizar `.equals()`, otra opción podrías ocupar `Character`, que es una clase de Java, y esta si contiene el método que deseas utilizar.

```java
    Character caract ;
```

---

Ahora bien, tal cual como tienes tu código, solo entrará a la primera palabra y luego se saldrá del ciclo, ya que estás diciendo que se repita el código siempre y cuando el primer carácter de la palabra sea un '<', ya en el primer ciclo esto no se cumple y termina la ejecución.

```java
        String texto = "Erase una vez el <lobo> y <caperucita>.";
        ArrayList<String> palabrasEncontradas = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner linea = new Scanner(texto);
        char caract  ;
        do{
            String palabra = linea.next();
            caract = palabra.charAt(0);
            if(caract == '<'){
                palabrasEncontradas.add(palabra);
            }
        }while(linea.hasNext());
         System.out.println(palabrasEncontradas);
```

**SALIDA:**

> `[<lobo>, <caperucita>.]`

Cambié un poco tu código, añadí un `ArrayList` de tipo `String`, para guardar las palabras correspondientes y así poder visualizarlas más adelante.

Agregué un `if`, en donde se toma la palabra y se guarda en el `ArrayList`, si es que esta comienza con `<`.

En el `while`, agregué una clausura diferente `linea.hasNext()`, ya que solo se devolverá al `do`, si es que `linea` tiene una siguiente línea, sino rompe el ciclo.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Datos primitivos en Java](http://www.manualweb.net/java/tipos-datos-primitivos-java/)

Answer (score 1):

El error:

> cannot find symbol:   variable caract

Indica que la variable que intentas usar, no se encuentra definida, si observas la variable esta siendo definida dentro del bucle, por lo que la variable no esta siendo encontrada.

```
    String texto = "Erase una vez el <lobo> y <caperucita>.";
    Scanner linea = new Scanner(texto);
    do{
        ...
        ...
    }while(caract.equals("<"));
```

Debes declararla afuera del mismo, además debes hacer uso del método `hasNextLine()` para terminar el bucle:

```
String texto = "Erase una vez el <lobo> y <caperucita>.";
Scanner linea = new Scanner(texto);

char caract;
do{
    String palabra = linea.next();
    caract = palabra.charAt(0);
    if(caract == '<'){ //Busca caracter <
        System.out.println(palabra);    //Imprime palabra  
    }
}while(linea.hasNextLine());
```

salida:

```
<lobo>
<caperucita
```